# PHP Select key in multi-dimentional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am working on a project where I select multiple items from a database (say 20) and store them in the cache in an array. I then need to remove the item from the array when the user clicks on the item.

Rather than deleting the cache and re-firing the query every time this happens (which was suggested by a colleague) I would like to simply remove the item from the cache and only re-fire the query when there are a limited number of items in the cache (say 5)

The array coming from the cache looks like this:

```
[
    [
      'item_id' => 10001,
      'item_name' => "super-cool item",
      'item_description' => "This item is awesome"
    ],
    [
      'item_id' => 10002,
      'item_name' => "super-cool item",
      'item_description' => "This item is awesome"
    ],
    [
      'item_id' => 10003,
      'item_name' => "super-cool item",
      'item_description' => "This item is awesome"
    ]
]
```

The array gets shuffled before three items are selected and shown to the user.

Obviously what I need to do is select an item based on the `item_id`, unset that item's key and reset the field in the cache.

The part that is tripping me up is selecting the item based on `item_id`, so what is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: why not just use the itemid as key in your array when you fetch from the db then you can just `unset($arr[$item_id]);`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you need, but it sounds a bit like a job for JQuery and AJAX. EDIT: ignore that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a difference a few years makes! Incase anybody else is seeking the solution to a similar problem to this, the best way to deal with it would be an approach like this:

```
$toDelete = 1234;

$cache = array_filter($cache, function ($item) use ($toDelete) {
    return (int) $item['id'] !== $toDelete;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete an index in an array you use the `unset()` function.
Because you have so few values you could just loop through the array and look for the array key for an item id:

```
<?php
$todeleteId=15;
foreach ($cache as $key=>$value) {
  if ($value['item_id']==$todeleteId) {
    unset($cache($key);
    break;
  }
}
```

Also you could just set the array keys to the item id and then just:

```
unset($todeleteId);
```

Comment: I had considered both of these options, however the website gets massive amounts of traffic so the foreach() method is used sparingly, the other option would be ok except that the shuffle resets array keys!

Comment: @AndrewWillis You must be very restricted when writing code, if you have to avoid loops. Why not give the processing to the browser by letting javascript handle your array?

Comment: Don't discard the foreach solution so fast! When only the first three items are displayed to the user, the foreach loop will run a maximum of 3 times before it hits the desired spot.

Comment: There's 20 items in the array that I need to search through, for each interaction I will need to find the element in the array. Doing this in the browser is not viable either as it is for unsetting a key in a `Memcached` cache.